# Docker Java application - SSLHandshakeException / No trusted certificate found

Tags: java, ssl, docker, gradle

I've created DockerImage for virtual building agent machine for CI.

On host machine I have installed JAVA.
JAVA is linked to docker container via VOLUME.
host(with Java) -- VOLUME -- docker container

java is working perfectly from docker container.

Project is using gradle. When gradle tries to download dependencies, error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

When I use wget to download the very same URL as gradle, it works on both -- inside a docker container and host machine.

Host machine/docker container: ubuntu:16:04

Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: The correct way to "solve" questions is to post your own answer and accept it. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I posted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't mount `/etc/java-8-openjdk` and `/etc/ssl` .

Comment: So how did you mount it?